# What is the idea of Xamarin's cross-platform app vs. native app development?

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin, cross-platform

I am currently reading up on Xamarin and have stumbled upon a topic that confuses me. My intent is, to develop an iOS app as the target of my project. However, due to other circumstances, I can only test on an Android Phone right now and first in the last part of the development on an iPhone. Therefore, the app would have to be initially developed and tested for Android and then later on - through Xamarin - deployed as an iOS app.

In Visual Studio with Xamarin installed, there is a choice of using native app development such as Xamarin.iOS, Xamarin.Droid and Xamarin Windows app. As far as I was told by some more experienced programmers, it does not matter which of those three apps/platforms one would choose for the initial development as it is always possible - again through Xamarin - to deploy to whatever platform is required in the end.

Now there is also a fourth app solution in the project menu, called "cross-platform" and this confuses me. As I understand, this is a general app choice virtually fulfilling the same purpose as the native apps, mentioned in the previous paragraph - deployment to whatever platform is desired at the end of the project.

**Unless I have misunderstood something here, what exactly would be the difference or idea of having a so called "cross-platform app" as a fourth choice if it can basically do the same as the native apps?**

Comment: I'm extremely surprised, that 4 people felt the need to down vote a perfectly legit question, intended to generate knowledge as to benefit all. As someone in another thread once noted, when a person apologized in advance(!) for asking a question, it seems quite sad to feel the need for just that. The attitude of some people is incredibly hostile, even toxic at times. I asked several questions lately and got great results by good answers, now this? Thanks guys for removing reps I could have used to up-vote a question from someone as a thanks. Where else would you like me to I ask this question?

Comment: I edited my post within the rules as to be in line with the rules. Now it's closed...?! Would the person that has closed this thread either reopen it at once or get back to me with an explanation. Thank you.

Comment: After no response to my request and instead of a permanent closing of the thread without any explanation (although having edited the part in question, relating to the "closed as primarily opinion-based" complaint), there is only one answer to this type of disrespectful behavior and that's..., https://hackernoon.com/the-decline-of-stack-overflow-7cb69faa575d

Comment: I think this question is a matter for most native developers who tend to use cross plat form frameworks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Xamarin there is two approaches:

1. Traditional Approach where you share application business logic and you write UI specifically for each platform using Xamarin.Android or Xamarion.iOS APIs to target ~70% of code share.
2. Xamarin.Forms which is a library on top of the specific APIs (Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS) to help share UI as well to target ~90% of code share.

With Xamarin you generate a native app and keep in made the quote:

> Everything you can do in native with Java, Objective-c or swift you
>   should be able to do with Xamarin.

Comment: That is not a fact. You can get a lot more shared code when using the "traditional" approach. It all depends on how much UI code you have compared to business logic.

Comment: Thank you for your response, Anas. I think, it was the most useful answer until my post was "put on hold as being primarily opinion-based" which I frankly do not understand since there is no asking for opinions, rather than a request for an explanation of some Xamarin project types and their functionality, which can - in fact - only be explained with facts. Thus, I marked your answer as the right one although there is still the question left in terms of the "Blank app (native & portable)" under the "cross-platform" menu. If you have some input to that part, please post a comment below. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Xamarin does not magically make an app, you write for Android, run on iOS. At least not without creating an iOS app and all the UI etc. that goes along for that.

With Xamarin you create native applications, just written in C# instead of Java or Objective-C or Swift.

So why choose Xamarin? It enables you to share a *lot* of code. Depending on how you structure your code, there are some apps that achieve more than 90% shared code or more. However, that differs a lot from app to app, and differs whether you are using Xamarin.Forms or not.

You might be referring to Xamarin.Forms in your question and the project types that come with it. Xamarin.Forms is UI framework that runs on top of Xamarin.Android, Xamarin.iOS and UWP. However, note this is only a UI framework and it can potentially meet all of your needs.

However, Xamarin.Forms does not magically make a Android application run on iOS. The UI you write using Xamarin.Forms, has a huge potential to run and look fine on iOS too. However, it still runs in an iOS project and not the Android project. This would be the case for any other platform you are going to target.

Xamarin.Forms is an abstraction on top of those individual platforms to help you write your UI once and potentially run everywhere, among other features such as navigation and a service locator.

The project types you are referring to in the Cross-Platform section in Visual Studio, is just different ways of creating Xamarin.Forms apps. This can be in a Portable Class Library (PCL), which creates an assembly targeting the common subset of .NET capabilities of the chosen targets. Along the PCL there will be a application project for each supported platform.

The other type is creating a Xamarin.Forms App using a Shared Project type, which is different from a PCL. How? A Shared Project should be though off as a glorified file linking project. Eh what? Look at it as the files in the Shared Project are copied and compiled in the Application project itself when you build the project. So you can write platform specific code in that Shared Project. It does, however, not generate an assembly you can share with your friends just like the PCL does.

That was a lot of Xamarin.Forms talk. However, Xamarin.Forms is *not* the only way you can create a Xamarin app. Xamarin provides 1:1 exposure of the native API. Meaning, just like on iOS you create storyboards, ViewControllers, utilizing UIKit for Views etc. You can do exactly the same in a Xamarin.iOS project. The same goes for Xamarin.Android, where you will be able to create Widgets, Activities etc, simply in a Xamarin.Android project. Both of these yield a native App. However, in this case the UI is not abstracted, and gives you much more power to customize your App, without having to work against Xamarin.Forms.

Which one should you pick? That is up to you to figure out. Both approaches, yield fully *native* Apps with *native* UI. It just depends on whether you want more or less abstraction.

Comment: Thank you for your reply & detailed information. I think though, that you misunderstood my question. I am perfectly aware of the majority of the things you were explaining (I spent hours watching Xamarin University lectures about the set-up and functionality of Xamarin, the native approach vs. the forms approach etc.) I was just trying to understand "cross-platform". You mention in your seventh paragraph that it basically is a forms tool. However, the two first project types are Blank app (native & portable) with no mention of forms. So these do not differ from the rest but are forms, too?

Comment: Long answer, correct answer, detailed answer... why no upvotes?